# Inserting Pre Determined data in another table when creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi a Real Rails Rookie here. I am trying to write a basic customer mgmt system and when I create a new customer (customer table) I need it to also create 10 sub-records in another table (customer_ownership) with certain predetermined information which will then be updated/modified when we speak to the customer.

I am really struggling with this, do I try and call the sub_record create controller from the create customer controller or do I write a new controller action in the Customer Controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use an active record callback to perform the work you need done thst is associated with data creation.

Or use a service object design pattern to Perform all actions.

Or you can just add the code for the task to be done after create as a method and call the method directly instead of calling it with a callback.

Or this functionality could live on the model. All oth these options could be considered the “Rails Way” depending on who you talk to.

My preferred method would be...

In `controllers/my_object_contoller.rb`

```
def create
  @object = MyObject.create(my_object_params)
  my_private_method
end

private

def my_private_method
   # create auxiliary data objects here 
end
```

Also look into [ActiveRecord associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Because there are ways to create two data models that are programmatically linked or associated with one another using foreign_key ids on the DB columns.

Rails offers an excellent api for you to use which I’ve linked to the rails guide for above.

Such an implementation using active record associations might look like this...

```
# 'app/models/user.rb    

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  ...
end

# 'app/models/address.rb'

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

# 'db/migrate/<timestamp>_create_users.rb'

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string     :email
      t.string     :first_name
      t.string     :last_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# 'db/migrate/<timestamp>_create_addresses.rb'

class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.references :user,         null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string     :house_number, null: false
      t.string     :streen_name
      t.string     :city
      t.string     :state
      t.string     :zip_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This give us a new way to manipulate our data. If we create a new user and the extra data we want to add is the users address. Then we can just collect all this data in a form and then user the methods that including the has_one helper gives us. For example...

```
def create
  @user         = User.new(params[:user])
  @address      = Address.new(params[:address])
  @user.address = @address
  @user.save
end
```

Of course this is all pseudo code so you should really dive into to active record association link I placed above

Comment: What would your preferred way be

Comment: I would just create a private method at the bottom of my controller class.

Comment: @ChrisNash I updated the answer to show you what I would do. Please accept it as the answer and upvote if it helps!